# Pointer stability under Windows Vista

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista

I have been using Visual Studio 2005 under Windows XP Pro 64-bit for C and C++ projects for a while. One of the popular tricks I have been using from time to time in the debugger was to remember a numeric pointer value from the previous debugging run of the program (say `0x00000000FFAB8938`), add it to watch window with a proper typecast (say, `((MyObject *) 0x00000000FFAB8938)->data_field`) and then watch the memory occupied by the object during the next debugging run. In many cases this is quite a convenient and useful thing to do, since as long as the code remains unchanged, it is reasonable to expect that the allocated memory layout will remain unchanged as well. In short, it works.

However, relatively recently I started using the same version of Visual Studio on a laptop with Windows Vista (Home Premium) 64-bit. Strangely enough, it is much more difficult to use this trick in that setup. The actual memory address seems to change rather often from run to run for no apparent reason, i.e. even when the code of the program was not changed at all. It appears that the actual address is not changing entirely randomly, it just selects one value from a fixed more-or-less stable set of values, but in any case it makes it much more difficult to do this type of memory watching.

Does anyone know the reason of this behavior in Windows Vista? What is causing the change in memory layout? Is that some external intrusion into the process address space from other [system] processes? Or is it some quirk/feature of Heap API implementation under Vista? Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Under Linux there is since a longer time a heap randomizer that aims at avoiding buffer overflow attacks. Maybe it has finally been implemented also by MS?

Comment: Well, I know about this, but AFAIK it only works when you *reboot* the copmputer. More precisely, I heard that MS implemented their version to randomize things at each boot (don't know how it works on Linux). So, the behavior I observe in Vista doesn't seem to be related.

Comment: Although this might be something. I'm running VS 2005, which is 32-bit application that can debug 64-bit applications. AFAIK, it works through MS's remote debugging mechanism,. Could it be that Vista essentially "boots" a new 64-bit environment every time I start a 64-bit application from VS 2005 (thus causing things to get randomized)?

Comment: Looks like Vista does have heap randomization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430720.aspx

Comment: I think this is a good question, not because it represent a particular good way to attempt to debug code but it highlights a security issue and one small technique operating systems can use to defend against it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Windows Vista implements [address space layout randomization, heap randomization, and stack randomization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430720.aspx). This is a security mechanism, trying to prevent buffer overflow attacks that rely on the knowledge of where each piece of code and data is in memory.

It's possible to turn off ASLR by setting the [MoveImages](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/showthread.php?t=5237) registry value. I couldn't find a way to disable heap randomization, but some Microsoft guy recommends computing addresses relative to [`_crtheap`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/9260e0d9-9968-485a-ab9a-0eb96ba38ca4). Even if the heap moves around, the relative address may remain stable.

Comment: Thanks for the citation. :) It's one thing to speculate but nice to see the evicdence.