# How do I disable ASLR for heap addresses for a program compiled and linked with mingw-w64 GCC?

Tags: windows, mingw-w64, msvcrt, binutils, aslr

### Problem

I am using mingw-w64 GCC to compile and link a C program on Windows 10 Home, build 1809 (I know it's old--long story).  I want to disable Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) so my heap addresses do not change from run to run while debugging.  How do I do that?

Sample program:

```
// testaslr.c
#include <stdio.h>                     // printf
#include <stdlib.h>                    // malloc
int main()
{
  printf("allocation: %p\n", malloc(16));
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ gcc -o testaslr -g -Wall testaslr.c
$ ./testaslr
allocation: 00000000007A1420
$ ./testaslr
allocation: 0000000000A81420
$ ./testaslr
allocation: 0000000000BF1420
```

As you can see, the address returned by `malloc` changes each time.  I want it to be the same value on every run.

### Toolchain

I'm using mingw-w64 [x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z/download).  (I was previously using [x86_64-5.4.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0.7z](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.4.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-5.4.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0.7z/download), and saw the same behavior.)

```
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
[...copyright stuff...]
$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.30
[...copyright stuff...]
```

Although I am using cygwin shell utilities, I am not using the cygwin compiler or linker.  The executable is only linked with MSVCRT plus the usual Windows libraries:

```
$ ldd testaslr.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7fff5ad40000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7fff57f60000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7fff56fa0000)
        msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7fff5a3b0000)
```

### Attempt 1: --disable-dynamicbase

According to the [binutils documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html), there should be an option to `ld` called `--disable-dynamicbase` to disable ASLR.  But it is not recognized:

```
$ gcc -o testaslr -g -Wall testaslr.c -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase
E:/cygwin/home/Scott/opt/mingw64-8.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '--disable-dynamicbase'
E:/cygwin/home/Scott/opt/mingw64-8.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: use the --help option for usage information
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Meanwhile, `-Wl,--dynamicbase` is accepted but does not alter the behavior.

### Attempt 2: Clear DYNAMIC_BASE afterward

I found a utility called [setdllcharacteristics](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2010/10/17/setdllcharacteristics/) that purports to clear the ASLR flag in the executable.  However, running it seems to indicate the flag is already false:

```
$ setdllcharacteristics.exe -d testaslr.exe
Original DLLCHARACTERISTICS = 0x0000
 DYNAMIC_BASE    = 0
 NX_COMPAT       = 0
 FORCE_INTEGRITY = 0
Updated  DLLCHARACTERISTICS = 0x0000
 DYNAMIC_BASE    = 0
 NX_COMPAT       = 0
 FORCE_INTEGRITY = 0
```

and the address is still different on each run after running that tool.

Interestingly, if I pass `-Wl,--dynamicbase` to the compiler, then `setdllcharacteristics` *does* show the flag as having been set, but after clearing it, the addresses are still different on each run.  This leads me to conclude that `DYNAMIC_BASE` is not what is responsible for the varying addresses.  But in that case, I don't know what is or how to change it, even after a lot of googling.

### Not attempted: MoveImages registry setting

I am aware there is a registry setting, `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\MoveImages` according to [this blog post](https://oalabs.openanalysis.net/2019/06/12/disable-aslr-for-easier-malware-debugging/), that might disable ASLR.  But according to that same blog post that requires a reboot, which is quite annoying, and ideally I only want this for the one program I am debugging, not my entire system.  I'm also doubtful changing that would have any effect given that clearing `DYNAMIC_BASE` did not.

### Speculation: MSVCRT switch?

If `DYNAMIC_BASE` is not the culprit, then perhaps this is something MSVCRT does on its own.  I found an [MSDN page that mentions heap randomization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb430720(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#address-space-layout-randomization-aslr).  The way the page is written, I can't tell whether that is controlled by the `DYNAMIC_BASE` flag, but my experiments seem to indicate it is not.  The text also says:

> Heap randomization is enabled by default for all applications running on Windows Vista and later.

but does not say how to disable it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to disable heap randomization. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1602765/1983398) for a related answer.

Comment: Heap addresses are not deterministic, and cannot possibly be. By the time the CRT is initialized (where `malloc` is implemented) the system has already loaded a bunch of DLLs that you have no control over, which may have occupied or reserved memory for their own use, and the set of such DLLs is not necessarily the same between runs.

Comment: @dxiv The set of DLLs loaded is shown in the `ldd` output.  It does not change between runs.

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate of [How to make malloc return the same address every time using MSVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740028/how-to-make-malloc-return-the-same-address-every-time-using-msvc) since I've determined the underlying cause is the same, even though I am using mingw instead of MSVC.  I'm choosing not to delete it, though, since I think other mingw users might benefit from the information and question link.

Comment: @ScottMcPeak The set of DLLs *may* be the same sometimes, but it's not guaranteed to *always* be the same. There are (legit) scenarios that can cause additional DLLs to be mapped into a process, or hooks which can inject code that allocates its own memory. For occasional local debugging, it might be enough if something worked most of the time, but it can't be guaranteed to reliably work every time.